# Show selected person in another panel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I   was playing with JavaScript in order to practice and wanted to make a list of people, which when clicked showed the person's details in another part of the screen.

Here's the code I used to achieve it, but I'd like to have your feedback; how would you do it? Here's a working snippet:

```js
const divRoot = document.querySelector('#root');
const tv = document.querySelector('.tv');
const tvProfesion = document.querySelector('.tvProfesion');
const tvNombre = document.querySelector('.tvNombre');

const personas = [
  {
    nombre: 'Julio',
    profesion: 'Web Developer',
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Yisus',
    profesion: 'Mesias troll',
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Goku',
    profesion: 'Sayayin',
  },
];

personas.forEach((person) => {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.classList.add('ul');

  ul.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    for (const prop in person) {
      if(prop == 'nombre') {
        tvNombre.innerText = person[prop];
      }else{
        tvProfesion.innerText = person[prop];
      }
    }

  });

  for (const prop in person) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = person[prop];
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  divRoot.appendChild(ul);
});

function setName(prop) {
  if(prop == 'nombre') {
    tvNombre.innerText = person[prop];
  }else{
    tvProfesion.innerText = person[prop];
  }
}
```

```css
div,li {
    border-radius: 15px;background-color: cadetblue; padding:5px
}

.ul, p {
    border: 1px solid grey !important;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:slateblue;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin:5px
  }
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(170, 165, 236);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .tv {
    border: 1px solid brown;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div class="tv">
          <p class="tvNombre"></p>
          <p class="tvProfesion"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd love to see other developers' ways of solving this problem in order to expand the small repertoire I have in my mind to solve this kind of problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few quick first thoughts:

You never use your const tv.

You never use your function setName(). also setName would be a wrong name for the function as it sets name and profession. Should be setPerson() instead.

You never use then event parameter of the event listener.

You should not create one event listener for each person in the person creation loop. Just add one event listener after creating all persons and check the event parameter target to get the right person to set

For me it makes no sense to set the properties in a loop when you have to add one if condition for each property you will set. To make it simple remove the loop and just use two lines of code setting number and profession directly.
If you want to make the code more flexible on adding more properties, I would suggest to use data tags in detail view naming the properties key.
For exmple:

`<p class="tvNombre" data="nombre"></p>`

then you can set your detail data in a loop by accessing the correct element just h\by the persons property key.

I only give you hints how to make your code better because I personal love it this way for myself if someone gives me a way not the complete answer. If you can’t figure something out for yourself or need any deeper information just ask.